# How can i make a button on a website play a mp3 sound from my computer?

Tags: html

*This question is not **exactly** about programming. what i want to achieve is simple...*

I have a mp3 file on my computer Ubuntu directory

```
/home/leo/sound.mp3
```

[image]

You see that blue button that says "ask question" in the screeshot?, I want to do "Inspect element" on that button in my browser and make it so when i click on the button it plays the `sound.mp3` file!

This is not a joke, i really used to do this but i forgot... thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Friend here is another way to solve your problem:

```
<button onclick="playMusic()">Play</button>

<script>
    function playMusic() {
        let audio = new Audio("./myMusic.mp3");
        audio.play()
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: playSound is not defined... what does this mean?

Comment: Friend here is another way to solve your problem:

<button onclick="playMusic()">Play</button>

<script>
    function playMusic() {
        let audio = new Audio("./myMusic.mp3");
        audio.play()
    }
</script>

Answer (score 1):

```
<button onclick="playSound()">Play</button>
function playSound() {
    var sound = new Audio("/home/leo/sound.mp3");
    sound.play();
  }
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: playSound is not defined... what does this mean?

Comment: you need to include this code in index.js file and use <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script> in your html file's <head>